# Laravel use @ function inside another @ function in View

Tags: php, html, laravel, sorting, localization

i want to use a function (@lang) inside another function (@sortablelink).

@lang: changed localisation depending on previous user input
@sortablelink: kysliks sortable columns (https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable)

Like this:

```
@foreach($COLUMNS_TASK as $column => $val)
         <div class="th">
              <a href=""><p class="justify-content-center text-center">@sortablelink($val, @lang('lang.'.$val))</p></a>
         </div>
@endforeach
```

When i run this code, i am getting this error: Error Call to undefined function lang()

But when i write it like this:

```
@foreach($COLUMNS_TASK as $column => $val)
         <div class="th">
              <a href=""><p class="justify-content-center text-center">@sortablelink($val)@lang('lang.'.$val)</p></a>
         </div>
@endforeach
```

It's working, but it only displays the results of the functions side by side, and it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use a function inside another function like this? Or is there another solution here i am not seeing?

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the translator to get the value you want and if you want to pass it as the second parameter to that `@sortablelink` directive you can:

```
@sortablelink($val, __($val))

// some ways to call the translator to get a translation
__($val)
trans($val)
Lang::get($val)
app('translator')->get($val)
```

The `@lang` directive would be calling the translator and echoing the result.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Localization - Retrieving Translation Strings](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings) `__` `@lang`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Facades - Facade Class Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/facades#facade-class-reference) `Lang`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick and helpful response :D Good to know that. I changed my code to: "@sortablelink($val, __($val))" and it does not give me a error message. However, it does not translate into the selected language. When i do "@lang("lang.".$val)" outside of the @sortablelink() function, it translates everything correctly.. strange

Comment: Nevermind.. i had to use "@sortablelink($val, __("lang.".$val))". Thank you so much!

Comment: sure what ever key you need to use, this is just showing you how to use the functions